# How can I run some code in github actions when the job is complete whether it passed or failed?

Tags: github, github-actions

I think what I want is to trigger an event on [`checkrun.completed`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events), but that event doesn't seem to fire...

What I'm trying to achieve is sending a slack notification when a specific job fails.

How can I run some code in github actions when the job is complete whether it passed or failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer, I'm looking for [these](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions) on the step

```
        if: failure()
```